# How can I add response.sendRedirect to my controller

Tags: java, servlets

I've written my controller to forward all requests and this works fine for nearly all actions that I want to take, but I may need to use response.sendRedirect for a successful login rather than forwarding it to try and implement Tomcat's CSRF prevention filter.

I've tried adding in what I believe is the correct code, but I keep getting errors can anyone tell me if this is possible and if what would be the best action to take.

My controller's login method as it currently stands is (without error code)

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
    String url = "";
    // Register a new user
    if (requestURI.endsWith("/subscribeToSite")) {
        url = subscribeToSite(request, response);
    }
    // Login
    if(requestURI.endsWith("/logintosite")){
        url = logintosite(request, response);
    }
   //Change AC password
    if(requestURI.endsWith("/changePwd")){
        url = changePassword(request, response);
    }

    getServletContext()
            .getRequestDispatcher(url)
            .forward(request, response);
}

private String logintosite(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    String url;        
    String message;
    // get values from form
    String pNum = request.getParameter("phoneNumber");
    String upwd = request.getParameter("password");

    //validate the values to check for empty values in case JS registration check has failed.
    if(pNum.length()==0 ||upwd.length()==0){
        message="You have not filled out the required fields.";
        request.setAttribute("message", message);
        url = "/login.jsp";
        return url;
    }
    //Format the phone number
    String mPNum=UserDB.formatPhoneNumber(pNum);
    //try to  login
    User user = UserDB.loginUser(mPNum, upwd);
    if(user==null){
        url = "/loginerror.jsp";
    }else{
           //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.invalidate();
            session=request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("loggedUsrID", user.getUserID());
            session.setAttribute("loggedUsrFName", user.getFName());
           url="/sched/welcome.jsp";

    }      
    return url;
}//EO user login
}
```

What I need to do is use response.sendRedirect(/sched/welcome.jsp) rather than send the URL just for this method as the other methods in the controller work fine just using forward.

Comment: How do you use the url in `doPost`?

Comment: Sorry realized I left out the requestDispatcher  and edited my post to include it.
 The user first visits a login page, fills in their phone number and password and posts to the controller.which as the post method ends with logintosite moves to the login method and if the login values match those stored in the MySQL db, the url is set to  url="/sched/welcome.jsp"; and the request is forwarded. But the url the address bar stays as /logintosite.
/sched/welcome.jsp then has a form to link to methods in another controller

Comment: What I meant is that the `doPost` method seems truncated.

Comment: Yes sorry added the dispatcer

Comment: Instead of returning a String, return an object containing the URL and a flag indicating if a redirect must be done. Or return a special url starting, for example, with "redirect:". I hope this is an exercise, and you realize that standard, much powerful and battle-tested MVC frameworks exist. Also, you shouldn't redirect to a view. You should redirect to the path of another controller.

Comment: It is an self learning exercise before moving onto Spring.
I have tried passing it onto another controller, but this doesn't work either.
Could you provide an example of the string with redirect